# Why cannot a user, with Edit own content permission, view a content item with the EditOwnContent requirement?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

We have the following code that successfully adds a menu item to the main menu.

The problem is that, when we grant Edit own content to a user, the user cannot see this menu item. Only if we grant Site Owners Permission, can the user see it.

What's up with that? Shouldn't granting Edit own content to the user do the trick?

```
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Aspects;
using Orchard.Core.Navigation.Models; // this doesn't resolve properly but still builds
using Orchard.Localization;
using Orchard.UI.Navigation;
using Orchard.Mvc.Routes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Orchard.Security.Permissions;

namespace BigFont.DealerDashboard.Services
{
    public class DealerDashboardMenuProvider : IMenuProvider
    {
        private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
        public Localizer T { get; set; }

        public DealerDashboardMenuProvider(
            IContentManager contentManager)
        {
            _contentManager = contentManager;
            T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        }

        public void GetMenu(IContent menu, NavigationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Add(T("Dealers"), "2", subMenu => subMenu
                .Url("~/Dealers")
                .Permission(Orchard.Core.Contents.Permissions.EditOwnContent)
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it. Please file a bug.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Sure. Does that mean creating a [new issue](https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)?